# change vertical menu to be horizontal

Tags: html, css

I have this css menu that is currently displaying a CSS / HTML menu vertical

```
#nav {
    margin:-20px 0 0 2px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%; 
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 4px 10px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    background: #666666; 
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
    width:155px;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
    background: #F36F25; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li ul li {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:-40px;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    color:#666666;
    border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    color:#f36f25;
    border:1px solid #f36f25;
}
```

how can i make it display horizontal rather than vertical?

I have created a fiddle here with the full HTML and CSS Code

http://jsfiddle.net/SV74d/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#nav li {
    display: inline;
}
```

And change:

```
#nav li a {
    display: inline;
```

to:

```
#nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
```

It will display your li elements inline and only stack them vertically when the viewport isn't long enough.

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle, i added this and it did not work. it kept the menu as it is

Comment: @user3179854 You can show those, but that's a different part of your code; you'd need to add a `#nav li a:hover` section.

Comment: @user3179854 I don't have the time to look into that, but it shouldn't be too difficult for you to uncover with a little effort; if you start with the element selector I mentioned in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You could float the li's left I suppose.

```
#nav li{
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically setting the li element to display inline

```
li {
    display:inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SV74d/2/

Comment: This creates a pretty bad overlay effect when the viewport isn't big enough to display them all on one line.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
#nav li {

    display : inline-table;
}
```

Comment: [Please consider explaining why this would solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I updated fiddle with that and thought that would help  : http://jsfiddle.net/SV74d/5/